# mysql insert into syntax, what order? How does it work

Tags: mysql

Couldn't find an answer to this and its a relatively simple query on how INSERT INTO command works.

When I run this command from PHP does it **search** the database for the names of the row or does it address them in numerical order.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(title, date, description) VALUES('$title', '$date', '$description')";
```

Database structure

1. title
2. date
3. description

So if I were to add another row to this table(becoming no.4) would it need to be addressed in order (i.e. after the 'description') or can I call it from anywhere as long as it has a corresponding position to the VALUES array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the order of the column doesn't matter at all as long as it exist in the table. But the order of values depends on how you declare the column name in the `INSERT` clause. The optimizer is not smart enough to determine that the value you are inserting is for specific column.

If ever you have interchange the values for the column and the data type doesn't match on the column, it implicitly tries to convert it to specific data type and if it fails, it then throws an exception.

Comment: So after the **INSERT INTO** part it finds that column regardless of position? And then in **VALUE** it just matches their position and inserts into what it has found

Comment: this is great news! saving me a lot of time :)

Answer (score 2):

If you explicitly set the column names (you do so by such substring $tbl_name(title, date, description))

... you may ignore the real order of columns.

Comment: I may sometimes disagree with this type of `INSERT` because a lot of times it can cause an error especially when the user don't include the auto incremented column during insert. Table may change its structure and sometimes it may add *nullable* fields. If fields are nullable and you use implicit insert, those fields are now required to be inserted with value unless you will insert *null* value. But my main point of this is when you modify your table, you will also modify your insert statement. This will give problems if this statement are precompile inside an application.

Comment: yes... but such things like unique keys or triggers are out of the scope of this question